# Can you see if a metrics was queried recently?

Tags: prometheus, thanos

Is it possible to know if a metric or a time-series was queried in last n days or n weeks?

I couldn't find anything in Thanos or Prometheus doc.

Thanks

Comment: I wanted to study metrics usage to see if what we collect is actually being used. I'm trying to reduce our metrics collection and eventually reduce the infra assigned to it.

Comment: I've actually found that Prometheus has a query log - https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/query-log/  - maybe the beginning of a solution

Answer (score 1):

I've actually found that Prometheus has a query log - prometheus.io/docs/guides/query-log

My plan is to parse the logs and extract the metrics from the query (using a log aggregator). I'll see where it goes.